# Built-in UserCreationForm throws "The two password fields didn't match" when passwords match. Django==2.2.2

Tags: python, django, validation, authentication

I'm setting up user registration with built-in User model and UserCreationForm. Problem is that form validation fails when proper credentials are given. And I can't understand why?

It looks like **form.cleaned_data** lacks 'password2' for some reason. But **form.data** has it.

Contents of POST is equal to **form.data**.

POST

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: 1EA7k5HUM7aDO1qj9DPslM18rz2QATZh0qtRd1R8iHc9MmnBgLGyUsO3YJzQjNwA
username: test
password1: qwe
password2: qwe
```

I have the same code in other project on django==2.1 and there's no problem.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.http import JsonResponse

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            return JsonResponse({'username': username, 'password': password})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({
                'error': 'Form not valid',
                'messages': form.error_messages,
                'cleaned_data': form.cleaned_data,
                'data': form.data,
                })
   else:
       form = UserCreationForm()
       return render(request, 'register_form.html', {'form': form.as_p()})
```

Template :

```
{% block content %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Expected:

`{'username': 'test', 'password': 'qwe'}`

Actual:

```
{"error": "Form not valid", 
 "messages": {"password_mismatch": "The two password fields didn't match."}, 
 "cleaned_data": {"username": "test", 
                  "password1": "qwe"}, 
 "data": {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "long string:)", 
          "username": "test", 
          "password1": "qwe", 
          "password2": "qwe"}}
```

Comment: Please add more details: the contents of a request.POST and a template that you're using for displaying a form to the user (if any)

Answer (score 1):

Info about form errors can be found in **form.errors**.
It appears that misleading form.error_messages field is used as constant just to store text. Shouldn't its name be all caps, though?

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
    password.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
```

Comment: This is true, might be confusing indeed. Now I'm curious why `form.is_valid()` returned `False`?

Comment: As Grin stated in this answer, the actual errors are to be found in `form.errors`.

Comment: I know, I was curious about what the exact error was.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the passwords were too short.

`UserCreationForm({'username': 'username', 'password1': 'pwd', 'password2': 'pwd'}).error_messages`

Results in `{'password_mismatch': 'The two password fields didn’t match.'}`. But:

`UserCreationForm({'username': 'username', 'password1': 'lalalalapwd', 'password2': 'lalalalapwd'}).is_valid()`

Results in `True`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you obey the rules

> Your password can’t be too similar to your other personal information.

> Your password must contain at least 8 characters.

> Your password can’t be a commonly used password.

> Your password can’t be entirely numeric.

For my situation i always skipped first rule. Hope it helps for someone.